# Parse non-valid HTML String in a variable into DOM with PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell, html-parsing

### Background

I want to get HTML contents from [a web site](https://kikakurui.com/x0/X0001-1994-01.html), then parse it as a HTML and extract some contents from parsed HTML DOM with PowerShell.

`Invoke-WebRequest` can get HTML from a URI, and `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject#ParsedHtml()` can parse HTML into DOM. But if the responce doesn't contain `charset` header, and the HTML contains non-ASCII characters, `ParsedHtml()` will collapses non-ASCII characters.

### Problem

When you want to get HTML content with proper encoding, you can convert the `HtmlWebResponseObject#Content` into a HTML string like this.

```
$RawContent = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri https://kikakurui.com/x0/X0001-1994-01.html
$HtmlString = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes($RawContent.Content))
```

But when you try to get DOM from the HTML string, `[xml]$HtmlString` will fail if the HTML content is not a valid XML.

```
PS C:\tmp> [xml]$HtmlString
Cannot convert value "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ja" xml:lang="ja">
(snip)
</body>
" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'src' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 38, position
15."
At line:1 char:1
+ [xml]$HtmlString
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument
```

On the other hand, `HtmlWebResponseObject#ParsedHtml()` can parse an HTML even if the content is not a valid XML, but there is no way to pass a string object into it.

### Question

Is there any way to parse non-valid HTML strings in a variable into DOM with PowerShell? The out-of-the-box features of PowerShell are preferable.

### Edit

The out-of-the-box features of PowerShell are preferable because we have to use a restricted VDI environment (we have to ask permission to install additional software) to do this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the [`HTML`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) syntax is based on the [`XML`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) syntax, it is not compatible in many ways. Therefore, (in most cases) you can't use a `XML` parser to read it.
Instead you need to use a `HTML` parser like the [`IHTMLDocument2 interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752574(v=vs.85)) to manupulate the contained elements.
As an example:

```
$Uri = 'https://kikakurui.com/x0/X0001-1994-01.html'
$String = [System.Net.Webclient]::New().DownloadString($Uri)
$Unicode = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($String)
$Document = New-Object -Com 'HTMLFile'
if ($Document.IHTMLDocument2_Write) {
    $Document.IHTMLDocument2_Write($Unicode)
} else {
    $Document.write($Unicode)
}
$Document.getElementById('page1-div').getElementsByClassName("ft01")[0].innerText
```

Yields:

```
本工業規格          JIS
```

Comment: is there any other solution - as on server core/hyperv server there is no such thing as webclient (which AFAIK needs internet explorer to work) and the com object also does not exist on my test machine.

Comment: Apart from the "*The out-of-the-box features of PowerShell are preferable.*", there is no background on this requirement in the question. Anyways, I guess the best way forward is to install some packages as [PowerShell Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows) (including [.Net Core 3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download)) and a 3rd party package as the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/). Otherwise, you will probably end up writing your own HTML parser...

Comment: @iRon Thank you for your answer. Your result seems to drop the first character （It should be `日本工業規格`）. Also, im my environment `[System.Net.Webclient]::New().DownloadString()` failed to detect text encoding (`$String` stored garbled string), so I had to use `$RawContent = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Uri $Uri` `$String = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes($RawContent.Content))` instead. But your idea (use `HTMLFile#write()`) is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!